# What does "the latter third of the year" mean?

Tags: expressions, idioms

I was reading a blog post on [Rust's 2018 roadmap](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2018/03/12/roadmap.html) (Rust is one of programming languages), and saw a sentence like below.

> We will continue to publish releases every six weeks as usual. But we will designate a release in the latter third of the year (Rust 1.29 - 1.31) as Rust 2018.

I was confused with what "the latter third of the year" means here, but couldn't any decent explanations out there.

Is this some kind of idiom or something?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 3):

If you divide the year into three equal parts, they are "thirds of the year".  By "The latter third of the year" Rust means the last of these three parts.  So it means approximately from September to December.  That is when he will "designate a release" which will be called "Rust 2018".

Comment: Really, thank you so much... at first I thought it says about quarters of the year as it was common, but it was divided by there parts so I was confused.

Comment: You should designate his answer as "accepted", since you clearly found his answer to be sufficient.